# I want to create a 2D array of points that links to my 2D array of components

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array

I am making a circuit diagram drawer for a school project and have a 2D array that stores whether 2 components are connected or not. I want to find a way to have an array that then stores the co-ordinates of these points so that if they are deleted, it can find the points and get rid of the connection

```
ElseIf P(1).X = Nothing And P(1).Y = Nothing Then 

        P(1).X = pointx
        P(1).Y = pointy

        Form1.Drawlines() 'run the DrawLines sub in Form1.vb

        NoOfNodes = NoOfNodes + 1 'increment the NoOfNodes Variable by 1
        Node2 = COMPONENTID
       Connections(Node1, Node2) = true
```

This is the code that stores the points being drawn, at the end the value of Connections is set to true to show that there is a connection between the components.

I need a way to have another array that can say something along the lines of:

```
Connections(Node1,Node2) = (P(1),P(0))
```

any contribution is much appreciated,

Charlie

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like each element in your array should point to an instance of a class.  On the class you can pack as many attributes and as much information about the connection as you like.

Comment: so I make a Connection Class and store information about it in there?